# python argparse - validating a subset of the command line

Tags: python, validation, argparse

I am trying to take a command string C which is imprecise and pass it to an object O. The object receiving this has a command grammar defined using argparse that I am not aware of. So it has the list of arguments, the allowed values per argument etc.

As I try to fix the input command string C, can I test whether a certain argument and its choices are valid as defined in object O?

E.g. object O has the following arguments defined:
--foo (valid values for foo are f1, f2, f3)
--bar (valid values for bar are b1, b2, b3)

I want to be able to call argparse on --foo alone and pass it b1, b2, b3 in which case I should get a False and I retry a different fix.

From the documentation I don't think this is possible - but maybe there is some other way before I extend ArgParse.

Maybe I need to look at some parsing/validation libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean something like `choices` parameter for the `add_argument` function of the parser in `argparse`?

Comment: `-h` or '--help' can be used to find what the parser accepts